# Where is defined number of idle persistent connections in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, php

I have PostgreSQL 9.6 and backend on PHP. When I use [Persistent connections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) to PostgreSQL via PDO PHP I have some idle processes. Command
`select * from pg_stat_activity;` shows me 3 idle process with query column `DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_0000013e`. I understand, that these processes wait new queries, but I not understand why are 3 processes? On other project with PostgreSQL I have 50 the same idle connections. Where this number is defined, why it depends?

Comment: The number of idle connections isn't defined anywhere. Those are created by your application code, not by Postgres.

Comment: It looks strange. I deploy my app on different Postgresql and one of them have 50 idle connections, other 95 idle connections. In my configs these numbers are not defined anywhere.

Comment: I found `pgsql.max_persistent` option in php config, and it's defined unlimited. But PostgreSQL give me 3 idle connection and no more.

Comment: It is the connection pool size in PHP. This should be on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks! It was in php and php-fpm configs, not in postgresql